# Target named "Google API" not found in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, google-api

I'm trying to import "com.google.android.maps.MapActivity" in my Eclipse project. To do that, i have installed Android SDK, Google API and almost everything in SDK manager. Updated everything and tried to change project properties under "Android" section to make build target as "Google API" but no luck. There is no Project Build Target named "Google API", there is only one option named Android 4.0.3. What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed it to work, thanks for everybody that tried to help. I've removed all the components for Eclipse and Android then reinstalled everything. I've done these steps at the first time I was installing Android (without the uninstallation of course) but didn't work, now it works. Weirdest thing, I guess first time doesn't count.

Answer (score 2):

Choose Window--> Android SDK Manager. Install Google APIs by Google Inc API 15. After installation the option will appear in the Build target.

Comment: Right click on your project -- > Properties --> Android. In the build target change it to Google Incs API 15.

Comment: There is no "Google Incs API 15" option, only "Android 4.0.3"

Comment: That means that you have not installed Google API 15 in eclipse. Use the procedure mentioned above.

Comment: I have installed. It looks installed in SDK Manager. I deleted the package reinstalled again still didn't help. I've restarted Eclipse, checked updates for everything, didn't help. I've already told this in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly make your project version with Google Inc version..And second one is that extend your class file with MapActvity in which file you want to show the map..Then further do the process accordingly..

Definitely it will work....

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand "make your project version with Google Inc version" part. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Means..when u make your project then select the version with google API.

Answer (score 1):

To use Google Api you should installed `Google Api` required Library From Android `SDK` Manager, and then create new Android Emulator and then run your application in that Emulator

Comment: I did that, mentioned in my question, didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

If this can help, I solved this by installing Google API in the android SDK Manager, then under Android 4.4.2,  "Google APIs (ARM System Image)".

After this, Google API appeared in build target